# import error - ImportError: No module named src.adec.forms

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to fix my website so that when I enter some details in a form, it saves in the database. Please let me know if I should re-phrase the question, I am new to this. When running python manage.py runserver I'm getting the below error on my console:

```
unknown-6c-40-08-a3-53-04:src vaijoshi$ python manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x10fbe6500>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 252, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/apps.py", line 15, in ready
    dt_settings.patch_all()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/settings.py", line 228, in patch_all
    patch_root_urlconf()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/settings.py", line 216, in patch_root_urlconf
    reverse('djdt:render_panel')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 549, in reverse
    app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 351, in app_dict
    self._populate()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 284, in _populate
    for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 401, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 395, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/vaijoshi/PycharmProjects/adec/src/project/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .views import *
  File "/Users/vaijoshi/PycharmProjects/adec/src/project/views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from src.adec.forms import UserForm
ImportError: No module named src.adec.forms
```

Structure:

[image: Tree updated]

projects/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render


# Create your views here.
from src.adec.forms import UserForm


def home(request):
    return render(request, "home.html")


def register_professional(request):
    return render(request, "registerprofessional.html")


def register_user(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = UserForm()

    return render(request, 'registeruser.html', {'form': form})


def terms_and_conditions(request):
    return render(request, "termsandconditions.html")


def how_it_works(request):
    return render(request, "howitworks.html")
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import *


class ProfessionalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Professional
        fields = '__all__'


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

Would appreciate any guidance.
Ty
```

After importing views.py from projects folder to src folder:

[image: views.py in src folder]

It gives me this same error:

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 395, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/vaijoshi/PycharmProjects/adec/src/project/urls.py", line 12, in <module>
    url(r'^termsandconditions/$', terms_and_conditions, name='terms_and_conditions'),
NameError: name 'terms_and_conditions' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Till what I know, in python you only need to import the file name, since the both file that is imported and the one that will import are in the same directory. If they are in the same directory (it can be the first "adec" folder, I think), just "import forms". That might work....

Posted as an answer because I am in a mobile and it don't have a "comment" button.

Comment: I tried what you suggetsed but am still getting the import error as shown above.  Unsure what to do.  Anyone have any ideaS?

Comment: I really think is something related to the directory... Try to import the class to a file outside it to see if this is the problem. BTW, what is your text editor (I liked it).

Comment: thanks, it's PyCharm :)  So to be blunt I'm a little new to Python so not too sure what you're suggesting I try.  Are you okay to spell it out for me a little? I have also added an updated tree.  The file currently sits in projects-->views.py

Comment: So, you have forms.py, a file the its in the currently directory (at least, inside you're project) /adec/src/adec/forms.py. What you're trying to do: import a class from this file, forms.py, to a file that is on the directory /adec/src/project/templates/view.py. What I think it's happening: the system is unable to find forms.py's path. Why? I think it's because you is making a go and go-back path. You get inside a folder, but to get to view.py you need to go outside this folder and get into another... I asked you to try to import the class to a file in the /src/ folder, to see if it works...

Comment: Okay I see, so @theshadlest I think I have made the correct changes. I took the views.py out of projects and cut and paste it into src.   I'm unfortunately still get a different error(please ignore what I wrote earlier, I had done a copy and paste of the code rather than a cut and paste ... see above, have attached it to the end of the question). The confusing part is now that termsandconditions.html has been defined... Let me know your thoughts

Comment: I did what you suggested and tried everything.  I think I managed to resolve the above error through another SO question but am not 100% sure. Am now seeing an error which says: ImportError: No module named src.project.models
Just to update.  My views.py (from above), I cut and paste into the views.py file in the src folder.  Was this correct?